# SQL State error while JDBC'ing to a db2 database

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I am using **JDBC** to connect to a db2 database and have the following sql to insert some values into the database.

```
sql="insert into HC_PROPF.PATIENT (given_name) values ('"+strArray[0]+"');";
```

However, I get a `SQL STATE` error as follows:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=@;ME) values ('Lorna');END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=3.66.46
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: In the future, you need to describe to us what the error is; often, this will tell you what the problem is, and where to look to resolve it.  In case you don't know that particular one, IBM has a [list of all the codes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/rsqlmsg.html).  Also, you should be using prepared statements, as depending on where `strArray[0]` is coming from, you may be open to SQL Injection (which is often the cause of data breaches); this is especially worrying as you look to be subject to HIPAA regulations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it without the last `;` in your query

```
sql="insert into HC_PROPF.PATIENT (given_name) values ('"+strArray[0]+"')";
```

According to [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n104.htm)  this is a syntax error